# How much quantity of water should be added?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

What quantity of water should be added to $16$ litres of $25%$ acidic solution to reduce it to $20%$ acidic solution ?

**Attempt.**

We have $16$ litres of solution, it has $4$ litres of acid and $12$ litres of water. Let i add $x$ litres of water to it and acid is $4$ litres. So total solution is $16+x$ litres. So I have 20% of $(16+x)= 20$ which gives me $x=4$. I am not sure though.

Thanks

Comment: Downvotes for what, posted my attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can solve it easily 
by focusing on the *non-changing material* , acid,

so total quantity after dilution to the required concentration =  $16\cdot\frac{25}{20}$,

and thus water to be added = $16\cdot\frac{5}{20}$ = 4 litres

Answer (score 1):

If you have 16 liters of  25% acidic water, then this implies that we have 16(0.25)= 4L of acid.

We want to know how much water we need to add to the existing 16L to obtain a solution that is 20% acid.

The 4L of acid does not change, so we can simply do 4L/0.20=20

So we must add 4 more liters of water.

Answer (score 0):

$20 \%$  of$(16+x)=4 $,not 20(because acid content after mixing water is 4)